# Cannot Type into OutlinedTextField when dropdownmenu opens below it

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make autocomplete feature by using `OutlinedTextField`, `DropdownMenu`.

When I programmatically open the `DropdownMenu`, I can then no longer type into the `OutlinedTextField`.

```kotlin
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val suggestions = remember { mutableStateListOf ("karan", "karanx", "karany") }
var selectedText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var dropDownWidth by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
Box() {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = selectedText,
        onValueChange = {
            selectedText = it
            expanded  = true
                        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .onSizeChanged {
                dropDownWidth = it.width
            } .onFocusChanged {
                expanded = it.isFocused
            },
        //why cant i do expanded = true on cliackable modifier of outlinetextfield
        label = { Text("Label") }
    )
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = {
            expanded = false
            focusManager.clearFocus()
                           },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { dropDownWidth.toDp() }).border(width = 2.dp,color = Color.Blue)
    ) {
        suggestions.forEach { label ->
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                selectedText = label
                expanded = false
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }) {
                Text(text = label)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This got solved by adding `focusable = false` to `PopupProperties` for the `DropdownMenu` like shown below:

```
 DropdownMenu(
                    expanded = suggestions.isNotEmpty(),
                    onDismissRequest = { suggestions.removeAll{true} },
                    properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false),
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
```

Full working code for autocomplete with Jetpack Compose Below :

```
            var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            var masterSuggestions = listOf ("karan", "priya", "vihaan")
            var suggestions = remember { mutableStateListOf <String>() }
            var selectedText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            var dropDownWidth by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
            Column() {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = selectedText,
                    onValueChange = {
                        println ("inside value change")
                        suggestions.removeAll{true}
                        selectedText = it
                        for (name in masterSuggestions)
                        {
                            if (name.startsWith(selectedText)) {
                                suggestions.add(name)
                             }

                        }
                                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    label = {Text ("label")}
                )
                DropdownMenu(
                    expanded = suggestions.isNotEmpty(),
                    onDismissRequest = { suggestions.removeAll{true} },
                    properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false),
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    suggestions.forEach { label ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                            selectedText = label
                        }) {
                            Text(text = label)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: It dosen't work when using ExposedDropdownMenu